# Changing HTML Text using a button (ASP .NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, button, dynamic, text

Is it possible to change the text in HTML format using a button in ASP or Input, for example:

```
Home > Accueil
Games > Jeux
```

(It's for translation)

Also, I'm only a beginner and I learn programming by myself, so please to say i'm stupid for asking such an easy question.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're asking.  Can you give us sample HTML and code that you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when changing text for specific languages is called Localization or Globalization. There are many ways to handle it, but the general approach is to include a resource file file for the different languages you want to support. Then instead of directly writing Home or Game in the text, you reference the resource files.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" meta:resourcekey="ButtonResource1" Text="English Button" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.100).ASPX